# Is Selenium Web Driver (Firefox) able to read AngularJS ng-model injected initial values?

Tags: jquery, selenium, angularjs, input

I have a text input field that is bound to a javascript object using ng-model.  The javascript object provides an initial value for the field.

```
<input class="class1 class2" type="text" ng-model="scopeVar"></input>
```

scopeVar is a text value.

When the page loads, Selenium (using the firefox driver) can find the input field, verify that it is visible, can enter text into the field and then read that text back, but it can not read the text that was initially in the field.

If I execute $('.class1.class2').val() in the firefox browser window it returns the expected default value.

If I execute ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("$('.class1.class2').val()") it returns null.
If I execute driver.driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".class1.class2")).getText() it returns null.

So it looks like Angular is correctly populating the DOM (as far a jQuery is concerned) but Selenium Web Driver can't read it.

Note: I do verify that I have an element and that it is visible before I try to read it.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: As an update...  If I stop the test in the IDE and type a value into the field Selenium can see the typed value and manipulate all results from then on.  If I set the values using element.sendKeys() or javascriptExecutor.executeScript( "$('.class1.class2').val('foo')" ) before typing directly into the field in the browser, the browser display is updated but calling any of the read methods returns null (or blank string) and executing javascriptExecutor.executeScript( "$('.class1.class2').blur()" ) causes the default value to be redisplayed (though it can not be read).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know about your app specifically, but this works against a ng-model mapped input field:

```
    WebDriver wd = new FirefoxDriver();
    wd.get("http://jsfiddle.net/SAWsA/11/show/");
    WebElement input = wd.findElement(By.tagName("input"));
    input.sendKeys("hello");
    input = wd.findElement(By.tagName("input"));
    System.out.println("fieldValue=" + input.getAttribute("value"));
    wd.quit();
```

And there's also [ngWebDriver for Java](https://github.com/paul-hammant/ngWebDriver).

Comment: The problem is with reading the initial value.  If you add a default value to your input tag      `$scope.query="query goes here";` and then try to retrieve that before you send the keys: `String s = input.getText();
     System.out.println( "initialValue="+s);`  You will see that the result is an empty string.

Comment: While this answer did not specifically address the issue it did provide the answer.  Rather than using `input.getText()` I should have used `input.getAttribute("value")`, though why that should matter to Selenium I have no idea.

Comment: The getAttribute("value") for fields, has always been true for WebDriver.  Your problem is still outstanding?  Can you make a full testcase reproduction ?

Comment: I still have one question.  Why does the javascript executor return a different value than entering the same javascript in the console of the web page?